# Is `long` identical to `long long` on LP64?

Tags: c++

Looking through a [fundamental C++ type reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types), you see that on LP64, `long` is 64 bits, just like `long long` on the same platform. Does that mean that these two types are identical on an LP64 platform?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't see how that's useful. `long` and `long long` are two different types, even if they happen to have the same size.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: "can be substituted for in all cases".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't. It only means that they are equally wide.

Comment: @DunPeal At the very least, `long l; long long *p = &l;` is supposed to give a compile-time diagnostic regardless of whether the sizes match.

Comment: @DunPeal In a compiler warning/error and possible undefined behavior.

Comment: @hvd: understood, but is there any practical difference other than the name?  For instance, if a program was not using any external libraries, could we always substitute `long` for `long long` and witness no observable effect?

Comment: @DunPeal No, we couldn't -- as I've mentioned, there are cases (for example, aliasing through pointers of incompatible base types) where this substitution would lead to UB.

Comment: @DunPeal Like H2CO3 hinted, possible undefined behaviour. `long l; long long *p = (long long *) &l; *p = 3; return l;` is not guaranteed to return 3.

Comment: @H2CO3, thanks guys, though I'm really not sure why there *should* be a difference between what appears to be two identical physical representation. I guess it's technically UB because the standard doesn't address this possibility.

Comment: @DunPeal [And some errors as well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b93f4b238cef4dd).

Answer (score 0):

No, take for instance:

```
 void foo(long);
 void bar()
 {
   foo(5L);
 }
 void foo(long long val)
 {
   std::cout << val;
 }
```

This fails to link.